# Eliminate Inner Loop

Tags: powershell

i have two loops in my program.First loop for setting up the retry peocess and inner loop for testing a connection status.

```
for($retry=0;$retry<=3;$retry++)
{
while (!(Test-Connection "mycomputer"))
   {
    if (time exceed)
    {
    $status=$false
    Write-Host "machine is offline"
    break
    }
}
if($status)
{
Write-Host "machine is online"
break
}
```

}

is there any way to eliminate the inner loop without changing the output

Comment: it does not look like c# to me...moreover your Q is quite unclear

Comment: it is not c#,moreover it is powershell.I just need the logic only not the code.Since powershell is based on .net i just put c# and .net also :-)

Comment: @user1654136 On Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network, tags are used to help experts find questions they are experts on. A C# expert isn't going to be helpful here, nor is a .NET expert. You need a Powershell expert. I've edited your question's tags to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "time exceeded" - time to do what?

If you want to wait between Test-Connection attempts, you can introduce an artificial delay with `Start-Sleep`:

```
$Computer = "mycomputer"
$TimeoutSeconds = 5

for($retry=0; $retry -lt 3; $retry++)
{
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet){
        # Didn't work
        Write-Host "Machine is offline"
        # Let's wait a few seconds before retry
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $TimeoutSeconds
    } else {
        Write-Host "Machine is online!"
        break
    }
}
```

---

The easiest way however, would be to use the `Count` and `Delay` parameters of `Test-Connection`:

```
$Status = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 3 -Delay $TimeoutSeconds
```

Comment: test-connection also have a `delay` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a loop as test-connection already have a `count` parameter

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already go in depth about why you don't really need a loop but I wanted to add a solution to your refactoring question.

You can eliminate the inner loop and if statement by pre-initializing a `$Result` variable and changing it in your original loop if necessary.

Personally, I find this more readable *(subjective)* at the expense of an extra assignment up front.

```
$Result = "machine is online";
for($retry=0;$retry<=3;$retry++) {
    while (!(Test-Connection "mycomputer"))
       {
        if (time exceed)
        {
        $Result = "machine is offline"
        break
        }
}
Write-Host $Result
```

---

**Edit** To test for multiple computers in parallel, I use following worflow

```
workflow Test-WFConnection {
  param(
    [string[]]$computers
  )
    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {        
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
}
```

called as `Test-WFConnection @("pc1", "pc2", ... , "pcn")`

Not much of a difference when every computer is online but a world of difference when multiple computers are offline.